# rx bytes increases on transfer out

Tags: networking, ifconfig

When I transfer data from one machine to another, I'm seeing an increase in both RX bytes and TX bytes according to both ifconfig and ip -s link:

before the transfer, on sending node:

```
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:a9:05:44:c2:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    **1553791138** 1916309  0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    **1035423346** 1330442  0       0       0       0
```

command used to send data ( with listening socket on the other end):

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=400000 count=50 | netcat 14.4.12.5 20000
```

after transfer, on sending node:

```
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:a9:05:44:c2:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    **1574414164** 1921752  0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    **1055706644** 1334263  0       0       0       0
```

As you can see, TX bytes and RX bytes have both increased by the same amount. This is the case on the receiving node as well.

My understanding is that TX is sent, RX is received. so why would they both increase on a one way transfer? If I specify UDP, then it works as expected - TX increases on sending node, RX increases on receiving node. But it can't be just due to the control messages in TCP, as that shouldn't be as much as 20MB? what am I missing? This is between amazon EC2 instances, and also I see this behaviour between 2 physical blades networked together.

Comment: Is sack, fack and dsack enabled?  `sysctl -a | grep ack`

Comment: @Aaron yes, all 3 enabled on both sending and receiving node

Comment: The only other time I would expect that is if the the interface is used as a router or vpn gateway.  Nothing else comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: Use /dev/urandom  sending all zeros isn't a good idea when doing any kind of testing. Causes all kinds wierdness due  to the fact that it can be compressed so well.